# LWJGL doesn't recognize OpenGL on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, raspberry-pi3, lwjgl, jogl

So I am trying to run a LibGDX game which uses LWJGL as a backend on my Raspberry Pi 3. I tried various gl driver combinations on the pi:

- experimental driver: game start but crashes soon after with JVM Errors, totally unstable
- no experimental driver: software rendering seemes to be used, very slow
- propretairy driver only (mesa uninstalled): LWJGL fails at initializing gl and crashes (stacktrace below)

Since I think the proprietary driver is the most stable GL driver I intend to use it. Also, I know that OpenGL is working because of glxgears an JOGL working fine.

So, has anybody any hint or an idea where to start looking? Is this a LWJGL issue or a GL driver issue?

Thank you in advance,
Manuel

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.
       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:322)
       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:216)
       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:144)
       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
    Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:831)
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:314)
       ... 3 more
```

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1810956.html

Comment: The Raspberry Pi does not have a nvidia card

Comment: what's your driver ?

Comment: actually I am not sure anymore. Before, when I uninstalled the mesa driver, another driver kicked in with stable open gl support. But i can't reproduce it anymore, and honestly I am not quite sure how to manage the graphic drivers on the raspberry pi...

Answer (score 0):

LWJGL and LWJGL3 do support the open-source (Mesa) OpenGL driver. The numerous demos of Minecraft Java Edition for Raspberry Pi demonstrate this.

In fact LibGDX runs smoothly on a Raspberry Pi 3 as shown by PokeMMO.

The right direction is to pursue the open-source driver, which at the time of writing is no longer labeled experimental. In fact it is the only way to use accelerated 3D graphics on a Raspberry Pi 4.

> Since I think the proprietary driver is the most stable GL driver I intend to use it. Also, I know that OpenGL is working because of glxgears and JOGL working fine.

JOGL has the advantage of supporting both the proprietary GLES driver (for a Pi Zero) as well as an OpenGL backend. The proprietary driver cannot run full OpenGL though, so it may appear to work only because the Pi 3's CPU is sufficient to run glxgears in software rendering at full speed.